# Adding up columns and selecting columns with largest sum

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, sum, dataframe

I am looking to sort a dataframe. I have this dataframe:

```
Y    X1  X2  X3
Y1   1   0   1
Y2   1   0   0
Y3   1   0   0
Y4   0   1   0
```

There are a lot of columns. I want to select the X values with the largest sum if you added down the columns.

I have been trying to do this by adding a row like so:

```
Y    X1  X2  X3
Y1   1   0   1
Y2   1   0   0
Y3   1   0   0
Y4   0   1   1
sum  3   1   2
```

and then I would sort it by the sum row

```
Y    X1  X3  X2
Y1   1   1   0
Y2   1   0   0
Y3   1   0   0
Y4   0   1   1
sum  3   2   1
```

and select 30 columns to use. However, I can only get a sum of the rows like so:

```
Y    X1  X3  X2  sum
Y1   1   1   0    2
Y2   1   0   0    1
Y3   1   0   0    1
Y4   0   1   1    2
```

using

```
pivot_table['sum'] = pivot_table.sum(axis=1)
```

I also tried

```
pivot_table['sum'] = pivot_table.sum(axis=0)
```

and attempted to add `.transpose()` but this isn't working. I also think there is probably a faster way to do this than the step-by-step attempt I am making.

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to sum column-wise and then just sort the column so that the highest values appear first column-wise?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `sum` on the df, this will return a Series, you can then sort this series and then use the index of the series to reorder your df:

```
In [249]:
# note that column 'X3' will produce a sum value of 2
t="""Y    X1  X2  X3
Y1   1   0   1
Y2   1   0   1
Y3   1   0   0
Y4   0   1   0"""
# load the data
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', index_col=[0])
df

Out[249]:
    X1  X2  X3
Y             
Y1   1   0   1
Y2   1   0   1
Y3   1   0   0
Y4   0   1   0
```

The result from `sum` will return a series we want to sort this and pass params `inplace=False` so it returns a copy and `ascending=False`:

```
In [250]:
# now calculate the sum, call sort on the series
s = df.sum().sort(ascending=False, inplace=False)
s
​
Out[250]:
X1    3
X3    2
X2    1
dtype: int64

In [251]:
# now use fancy indexing to reorder the df
df.ix[:,s.index]

Out[251]:
    X1  X3  X2
Y             
Y1   1   1   0
Y2   1   1   0
Y3   1   0   0
Y4   0   0   1
```

You can slice the index if you want just the top `n` columns:

```
In [254]:
df = df[s.index[:2]]
df

Out[254]:
    X1  X3
Y         
Y1   1   1
Y2   1   1
Y3   1   0
Y4   0   0
```

Comment: Update for Pandas 1.1.5: sorting a series or data frame uses `pd.DataFrame.sort_values`. See the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use describe() on your dataframe to get statistics per column (which includes sum). Then use sort on the dataframe using the column with max sum from describe result.

I would say it is generally not a good idea to add a row with different semantics than other rows to the DataFrame. It is not an Excel.

Comment: The OP wants to use the sum values to reorder the df

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar problem where I just wanted to keep the columns with with the largest sums. Here is my solution:

ncols is how many columns to keep

```
def top_cols(dftemp,ncols):
    dfsum = dftemp.sum().to_frame().reset_index()
    dfsum = dfsum.sort_values(by=0,ascending=False, inplace=False).head(ncols)
    top_cols = dfsum['index'].tolist()
    return dftemp[top_cols]

df = top_cols(df,50) #this would return the dataframe with the 50 columns with the largest sums
```